# пробник в тг боте

Tags: python, telebot, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Я пишу своего телеграм бота на Python, и хочу реализовать пробный тест с подпиской, чтобы у пользователя была одна попытка протестировать действие с кнопку, а затем, когда попытка исчерпана, ему нужно оплатить подписку в боте чтоб он мог использовать его дальше.., но я не могу это сделать :(, пожалуйста, помогите!

Answer (score 0):

Пробную подписку можешь реализовать с помощью базы данных, например `sqlite3`, а [**тут**](https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter4.html) написано как реализовать платёжную систему. Но готового бота тебе тут не напишут.